# How do I run a specific formula in Excel but have it ignore the formula if blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently running this formula `=ROUND((AVERAGE(B3:AX3)/2)*100, 0)` but if `B3:AX3` has no values at all, I get `#DIV/0!` appearing in the calculation cell.

How do I adjust my formula so that excel will give me a 0 in place of the calculated result if `B3:AX3` has no values to calculate?

Alternatively, how can I get excel to just completely ignore the formula, leaving the cell blank, if there are no values in `B3:AX3`?

Comment: [**IFERROR function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)?

Comment: One another way: `=IF(SUM(B3:AX3)=0,0,ROUND((AVERAGE(B3:AX3)/2)*100, 0))`

Comment: Or else: `=IF(COUNT(B3:AX3), ROUND((AVERAGE(B3:AX3)/2)*100, 0), 0)`

Comment: You may also see article: [How to correct a #DIV/0! error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/how-to-correct-a-div-0-error-3a5a18a9-8d80-4ebb-a908-39e759a009a5#:~:text=Microsoft%20Excel%20shows%20the%20%23DIV,as%20shown%20in%20this%20picture.)